# Response didn't back from Node js backend

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, api, redux

I sent request from my React Application into node js backend but it doesn't response the request also it confirm changes..
i use Redux and Redux-Thunk and i wanna dispatch an action after get response from backend but change happen in backend but didn't response any data and its not work.

> I wanna update user information then dispatch an action to update data in redux store too, but this update only happen in backend, i mean after update in backend the action doesn't dispatch..

`ITS MY REACT CODE`

```
export const updateDetails = (name, email, password) => {
  const locals= JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("user"));
  const token = locals["token"];

  const newDetails = { name, email, password };
  const everyThing = {
    newDetails,
    id: locals["id"],
  };
  const newEvery = JSON.stringify({ everyThing });
  return (dispatch) => {
    dispatch(profileUpdateRequest());
    fetch("users/auth/updateProfile", {
      method: "PUT",
      headers: {
        authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
      },
      body: newEvery,
    }) //After That Not Dispatch any action even nothing work
      .then((res) => {
        console.log(res); // Even Doesn't log this
        dispatch(updateProfileUI(newDetails));
      })
      .catch((err) => {
        dispatch(updateProfileFail(err.message));
      });
  };
};
```

it works for another requests but didnt't work for this one

Comment: If you put a console.log in your catch, does something happen there? Did you remember to `dispatch(updateDetails(...))` and not simply call `updateDetails()` on its own?

Comment: Yeah bro i put console.log in catch, but nothing happened, and i dispatched `updateDetails` and thats code `[ const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {
  return {
    UpdateProfile: (name, email, password) =>
      dispatch(updateDetails(name, email, password)),
  };
};
`]